# rails link_to add post.id to href

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I'm using rails 4.

Is there any way to add post.id to link_to href?

```
<%=  link_to_modal "Demo Form", "#demo-form-"+post.id, :class=>"button" %>
and
<%=  link_to_modal "Demo Form", "#demo-form-"(post.id), :class=>"button" %>
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. Did you try: `<%=  link_to_modal "Demo Form", "#demo-form-#{post.id}", :class=>"button" %>` ?

Comment: `post.id.to_s` should also have worked: `<%=  link_to_modal "Demo Form", "#demo-form-"+post.id.to_s, :class=>"button" %>`, but I like @Surya's answer better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`<%= link_to_modal "Demo Form", "#demo-form-#{post.id}", :class=>"button" %>`

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer to point out the error and how you could have fixed it with your existing code.

The only problem with this line:

```
<%=  link_to_modal "Demo Form", "#demo-form-"+post.id, :class=>"button" %>
```

is that you're trying to concat a `Fixnum` with `string` which should have generated `can't convert Fixnum into String` error.

You could have used `post.id.to_s` to fix what you already had as:

```
<%=  link_to_modal "Demo Form", "#demo-form-" + post.id.to_s, :class=>"button" %>
```

And your second line:

```
<%=  link_to_modal "Demo Form", "#demo-form-"(post.id), :class=>"button" %>
```

is invalid and should have thrown a `SyntaxError`.

I'm unsure on your choice of syntax, but I like @Surya's answer better that uses the string interpolation.